# Why PowerCLI script creates duplicate records using get-vm?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am trying to build a script that will extract list of VMs from several vsphere servers. At this point it does what I want, but unfortunately it also creates duplicate values in results .csv file.

Just for note serverlist.txt and vicredentials.xml contains the same unique servers.

```
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -DefaultVIServerMode Multiple -Confirm:$false

if (Test-Path 'E:\vSphereScript\vCenterVMList.csv'){Remove-Item 'E:\vSphereScript\vCenterVMList.csv'}

$serverList = Get-Content -Path "E:\vSphereScript\serverlist.txt" 

foreach ($server in $serverList) {
$creds  = Get-VICredentialStoreItem -file "vSphereScript\vicredentials.xml" -Host $server
Connect-VIServer -server $creds.host -user $creds.user -password $creds.password
Get-VM | Select-Object Name, Guest, VMhost, ResourcePool | Export-Csv -Path "E:\ProgramData\vCenterVMList.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
Disconnect-VIServer $server -Confirm:$false

}
```

Also does anyone have idea why this is so slow?
If I connect to vm directly from powershell and use Get-VM it's almost instantaneous

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with your code but a couple things do come to mind:

- Why are you setting DefaultVIServerMode to Multiple if you're only connecting to a single vCenter at a time?
- When you say duplicates, is it the entire VM inventory from a vCenter or is it only particular VMs?
- Are the duplicate VMs from a singular vCenter or multiple vCenters?
- Are you using any replication based software? (example: SRM)

With regards to speed, `Get-VM` is fast. However, connecting and disconnecting from vCenter servers are not particularly quick actions.